# How can I create a keybinding that pastes in the terminal in bracketed paste mode, but only if the shell supports it?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, terminal-buffer

Xterm has a feature where if you put in `.Xresources`

```
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \
    Shift Ctrl<Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

then ctrl+shift+V will paste from clipboard.

I notice that when I paste from the clipboard with this shortcut then the pasted text will not trigger a new command and wrapped in "white background":

[image: screenshot of the terminal]

After some research I figure out that this is the [bracketed paste mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketed-paste) supported by xterm. I want to make a vim key binding that does the bracketed paste into an embedded terminal in vim (opened by `:ter` for example):

```
set termwinkey=<c-j>
" then <c-j>"+ pastes from "+ clipboard to the terminal
tnore <c-j>"+p  <esc>[200~<c-j>"+<esc>[201~
```

This works, unless the command running inside the terminal does not support bracketed paste...

[image: terminal output]

From my understanding xterm's ctrl+shift+V (if defined as above) can automatically detect whether the shell inside supports bracketed paste because the shell sends `^[[?2004h` to xterm, and if it's not seen then xterm will not send the `^[[200~`.

**Question**: how can the vim key binding above be defined so that it does the same thing as xterm's ctrl+shift+V?

(motivation: I want to paste from vim's `@"` selection instead, while ctrl+shift+V only allows pasting from `@+`)

---

Update: I notice that xterm has a feature to query whether bracketed paste is currently enabled...

Documentation: https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

We have

```
CSI ? Pm h
          DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
            [...]
            Ps = 2 0 0 4  ⇒  Set bracketed paste mode, xterm.


CSI ? Ps $ p
          Request DEC private mode (DECRQM).  For VT300 and up, reply
          DECRPM is
            CSI ? Ps; Pm $ y
          where Ps is the mode number as in DECSET/DECSET, Pm is the
          mode value as in the ANSI DECRQM.
          Two private modes are read-only (i.e., 1 3  and 1 4 ),
          provided only for reporting their values using this control
          sequence.  They correspond to the resources cursorBlink and
          cursorBlinkXOR.

CSI Ps $ p
          Request ANSI mode (DECRQM).  For VT300 and up, reply DECRPM is
            CSI Ps; Pm $ y
          where Ps is the mode number as in SM/RM, and Pm is the mode
          value:
            0 - not recognized
            1 - set
            2 - reset
            3 - permanently set
            4 - permanently reset
```

In other words, if the application inside prints to the terminal `^[[?2004$p`, the terminal will return `^[[?2004;answer$y`
where <kbd>answer</kbd> is one of {1, 2, 3, 4} as described above.

So I try doing something like this:

```
call writefile(["\e[?2004$p"], "/dev/tty", "b")
for s in "\e[?2004;"
    if getcharstr()!=s
        throw "Error"
    endif
endfor
let response=getcharstr()
for s in "$y"
    if getcharstr()!=s
        throw "Error"
    endif
endfor
echom response
```

it works, but always return 1 even if it's inside a terminal.

I'm not sure how TTY/PTY works unfortunately, so I don't know what to do next.

(but let's say `term_gettty(bufnr())` returns `/dev/pts/27`, then I can

- `printf '\e[?2004$p' > /dev/pts/27` to get as-if the response typed into the command running inside it, and
- `printf '\e]51;["call", "Tapi_log", ["123"]]\x07' > /dev/pts/27` to call vim terminal API.
  )

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow your question, but try `:help xterm-bracketed-paste`, and also note that you can copy the contents of the default register `@"` to one of the system clipboard registers `@+`, `@*` to make it pasteable by the system (better: you can yank _directly_ to such registers).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Even if I copy `@"` to `@+`, I still need to "simulate" a mouse click or ctrl+shift+V etc. to make xterm paste into the vim terminal, which is suboptimal; besides, that will destroy the existing content in `@+`. (`xterm-bracketed-paste` only explain how vim should be configured to handle xterm properly, nothing about how to paste things from vim into embedded terminal)

Comment: Is there a reason `<C-w>""` doesn't work? Edit: ah, this probably just inserts without any bracketed-pasting…

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way, although it needs some wrapper script...

First, save this wrapper script as `a.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import pty
import tty
import select
import subprocess

STDIN_FILENO = sys.stdin.fileno()
STDOUT_FILENO = sys.stdout.fileno()
STDERR_FILENO = sys.stderr.fileno()

def _writen(fd, data):
    while data:
        n = os.write(fd, data)
        data = data[n:]

def main_loop(master_fd):
    fds = [master_fd, STDIN_FILENO]

    data_processed = bytearray()

    while fds:
        rfds, _, _ = select.select(fds, [], [])
        if master_fd in rfds:
            data = os.read(master_fd, 1024)
            if not data:
                fds.remove(master_fd)
            else:
                last_pos = len(data_processed)
                for b in data:
                    data_processed.append(b)

                    if data_processed.endswith(b'\x1b[?2004h'):
                        # set bracketed paste mode
                        data_processed += b'\x1b]51;["call","Tapi_bracketed_paste",1]\x07'

                    if data_processed.endswith(b'\x1b[?2004l'):
                        # reset bracketed paste mode
                        data_processed += b'\x1b]51;["call","Tapi_bracketed_paste",0]\x07'

                    # TODO what about \x9b? https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-C1-_8-Bit_-Control-Characters

                _writen(STDOUT_FILENO, data_processed[last_pos:])

                # truncate to save memory
                if(len(data_processed)>=1024+30):
                    data_processed=data_processed[1024:]
                last_pos=len(data_processed)
                
        if STDIN_FILENO in rfds:
            data = os.read(STDIN_FILENO, 1024)
            if not data:
                fds.remove(STDIN_FILENO)
            else:
                _writen(master_fd, data)

def main():
    interactive_command = sys.argv[1:]

    if hasattr(os, "fsencode"):
        # convert them back to bytes
        # http://bugs.python.org/issue8776
        interactive_command = [*map(os.fsencode, interactive_command)]

    pid, master_fd = pty.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        os.execlp(interactive_command[0], *interactive_command)

    try:
        mode = tty.tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO)
        tty.setraw(STDIN_FILENO)
        restore = True
    except tty.error:    # This is the same as termios.error
        restore = False

    try:
        main_loop(master_fd)
    except OSError:
        if restore:
            tty.tcsetattr(0, tty.TCSAFLUSH, mode)

    os.close(master_fd)
    return os.waitpid(pid, 0)[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This stands between vim and the child process, to rewrite the content as necessary -- whenever the child process sends `CSI?2004h` the wrapper appends `ESC[51;["call","Tapi_bracketed_paste",1]\x07` to it to inform vim about the change, similarly for `CSI?2004l`.

Then put this in vimrc:

```
function Tapi_bracketed_paste(bufn, args)
    call setbufvar(a:bufn, "bracketed_paste_enabled", a:args)
endfunction
```

Then the "bracketed paste" command can simply be defined as follows:

```
function TermBracketedPaste()
    if b:bracketed_paste_enabled
        return "\<esc>[200~\<c-j>\"\"\<esc>[201~"
    else
        return "\<c-j>\"\""
    endif
endfunction
tnore <expr> <c-j>p TermBracketedPaste()
```

or, more simply,

```
tnore <expr> <c-j>p b:bracketed_paste_enabled ? "\<esc>[200~\<c-j>\"\"\<esc>[201~" : "\<c-j>\"\""
```

If you run `:term a.py bash` in vim, it will open a terminal but optional bracketed paste works.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476354/how-do-nix-pseudo-terminals-work-whats-the-master-slave-channel?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374000/how-to-use-pseudo-terminals-in-linux-with-c?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067878/write-program-that-pretends-to-be-a-tty?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30632435/5267751 (Python script taken from this answer with modifications.)

Comment: Although the linked answer states that the code may have a deadlock (I have not been able to confirm that)